# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError at Runtime: Need Class not on Classpath

Tags: java, jar, classpath, classnotfoundexception

I have tried several approaches as suggested on this website as well as several others to no avail.

-Running Angstrom embedded Linux, OpenJDK6, Shark VM.

### File Structure

All .java and .jar files are stored in directory ./src

- jarfiles: j1.jar j2.jar
- Source code: Coder.java, WrapperClass.java

### Compiling and Running

- javac -cp j1.jar:j2.jar Coder.java WrapperClass.java
- Successfully compiles, outputs Coder.class, WrapperClass.class, as well as several other files including Coder$1.class through Coder$6.class, as well as Coder$Main_thread.class and Coder$Progress_Bar_Thread.class, any insight onto what all these .class files are for?
- Run attempts all terminate in java.lang.ClassNotFoundException.

  - ~/coder/src: java Package.Coder
  - ~/coder/src: java -cp jar1.jar:jar2.jar Package.Coder
  - ~/coder: java ./src/Package.Coder
  - ~/coder: java -cp jar1.jar:jar2.jar ./src/Package.Coder

Thank you very much for your help. I have run this on NetBeans and can verify that it's functional code, just a matter of getting it to run on Linux.

Stacktrace is:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Package/Coder Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Package.Coder

at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)

at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)

at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:321)

at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)

at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)

Could not find the main class: Package.Coder. Program will exit

Comment: Provide the full details on the excption. 1. Is it `ClassNotFoundException` or `NoClassDefFoundError`? It's not irrelevant. 2. Which exactly class is not found?

Comment: Side notes: 1. you are apparently defining your classes in the root (default) package. This alone is a bad idea and can cause problems. 2. You are misusing the source directory as a place to keep the jars in. 3. It would be much better to use a separate destination directory for compiled classes.

Comment: You try to run a `Package.Coder` class, but there is no evidence of `Package` being a package since then the source files would need to be in the `Package` subdirectory. Never use uppercase letters in package names, though.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError,


Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException. Additionally, it's actually at ~/Desktop/Coder/src.

Comment: `NoClassDefFoundError` is always caused by an underlying `ClassNotFoundException`, but it is more relevant for diagnostics. You have still not provided the full information on the error.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this structure

```
/coder
    /src
        /Package
            /Coder.java
            /WrapperClass.java
        /j1.jar
        /j2.jar
```

You will need to compile from `/src` as

```
javac -cp j1.jar:j2.jar Package/Coder.java Package/WrapperClass.java
```

This will create `.class` files in `/Package`. You can then run it, again from `/src` as

```
java -cp j1.jar:j2.jar Package.Coder
```

assuming the `Coder` class has a `main` method which is your entry point.

Comment: I restructured as you suggested. Program compiles as you said it would as well. The Coder class does have a main method, ho


wever I receive the same error at runtime.

Comment: @User You must need a class that is not on your classpath. Please edit your question and the add the full stacktrace of your error.

Comment: That error would be: `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDeffoundError: Package/Coder

Comment: Is there a `Coder.class` file in the `Package` directory and are you running it from `/src`?

Comment: My apologies, but I am inexperienced with Linux. How can I provide a full stacktrace?

Comment: @user2819672 The stack trace is the full error message that is output from java.

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Package/Coder    
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Package.Coder  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:217)  
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)  
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:321)  
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:294)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:266)  
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassInternal(ClassLoader.java:334)  
Could not find the main class: Package.Coder.

Comment: @user2819672 That's the stacktrace. You'd be better off editing your question (little button at the bottom) and adding it there for others to see. Is your `Coder` class declared as being in the `Package` package?

Comment: Done and yes, both Coder and WrapperClass are declared as being in Package.

Comment: @user2819672 I don't know what to tell you. Try adding relevant information (class declarations, package structures) in your question and rewalking us through exactly what you do. You must be missing a step.